# Not able to login in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

In windows server 2008 r2, when I am pressing ctrl alt delete its taking me to workstation menu, so how to press it so that i can log in?

Comment: [This is a site for IT professionals; please read the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).  Having said that, as an IT professional, I'd be happy to talk you through your... key-pressing-troubles for $150 an hour.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/106320/how-do-you-send-ctrlaltdelete-to-windows-in-vmware-player

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Alt+Insert hotkeys.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little please ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/106320/how-do-you-send-ctrlaltdelete-to-windows-in-vmware-player